# Trying to pass an array to ajax as an array

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

Im trying to pass my array from a controller to my ajax results and then use the results to determine if I should show certain div or not. Below is my PHP controller.

```
public function actionCheckUser(){
    $user = $this->user;
    $has_name = $user['realname'] != '' ? 'name_tab' : 'none';
    $has_mobile_verified = $user['mobilestatus'] == 1 ? 'mobile_tab' : 'none';

    $check = array($has_name, $has_mobile_verified);
    $data['result'] = $check;
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

And here's my ajax

```
    var myarray = new Array();
$.ajax({
    url: "/member/CheckUser",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data){
        var myarray = $.parseJSON(data);
        array = myarray.result;
        myarray = array.split(',');
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    },
    //dataType:"json"
});

$(".tab").each(function(){
    if(jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('id'), myarray) !== -1){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#'+id).removeClass('tab');
        $('#'+id).hide();
    }
});
```

I'm not able to return it as array and it also didn't do anything to my div...

I'm trying to use the results to determine which div to hide and which to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, there is some issue with the way you are handling ajax response, You dont need to slit the array `myarray = array.split(',');` , variable `array` is already array with two values as per your controller logic, You should change your JavaScript logic as follows,

```
var myarray = new Array();
$.ajax({
    url: "/member/CheckUser",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data){
        var myarray = $.parseJSON(data);
        initializeTabs(myarray.result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       //alert(xhr.status);
       alert(thrownError);
    },
    //dataType:"json"
});

function initializeTabs(myarray) {
    $(".tab").each(function(){
        if(jQuery.inArray($(this).attr('id'), myarray) !== -1){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#'+id).removeClass('tab');
            $('#'+id).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: you're my life saver ! thanks, it's working fine now.